# Prevent MatDialog destroy component

Tags: angular

I have

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(
            ConfirmationDialogComponent,
            { width: '50vw', data: resume }
        );
```

but how can I avoid that mat-dialog destroy the component called "ConfirmationDialogComponent" ? because I have a subscriber of a behavior subject inside of that component and when mat-dialog is closed and re-opened again, the the response of the subscriber is null. Also all the apis that the component have are called again.

Comment: It's difficult to say without seeing your code but it sounds like you should extract that subject into a service

Comment: You can not, so another aproach is make the subscription in the component before open the dialog and pass as data or make a kind of "cache". Some in your subscription service `return  this.dataSaved?of(dataSaved):this.httpClient(...).pipe(tap(res=>this.dataSaved=res))`